# How to use direct payment paypal in India?

Tags: paypal

I am wanting to integrate `paypal` `direct payment` API in my webpage. This time I am using `paypal express checkout`. I want to switch to `direct payment paypal`. But the problem is, I found `direct payment paypal` is not supported in `India`. Where I can find the list of supported countries? So is their anyway to use this in India. Or any alternative for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, PayPal does not support Direct Payments in India. Unfortunately, there is no work around as far as PayPal Payment Gateway is concerned. It is supported in US,UK,CA.

[List of countries where PayPal PRO is supported](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/)

Comment: from paypal there is no alternate at this moment. You can use normal express checkout API's, where buyer can choose (pay with credit/debit card) as option to pay with direct cards(but again this is not guaranteed always) .

Comment: Anyother API same as paypal.?(not STRIPE)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of benefits of transferring your fund through Paypal. However You no need to use credit or debit card in order to open the PayPal account in India. You should provide only the correct details while creating your PayPal account. The accurate details help you to send or receive funds without any hassles. You can read on "How Does Paypal Work in india" Click http://intechbuzz.com/how-does-paypal-work-in-india-simple-guide-to-use-paypal/